# Vite includes module that does not exist - how to clear cache?

Tags: vite

I have a weird situation where I have removed a module from my project, yet Vite happily runs `dev` as if it was installed.

How do I clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered while writing this that you can do:

`vite --force`

which does what I want.